# What does this distribution look like?

Tags: distributions, modeling

I have data with the following empirical distribution[image: empirical distribution]. What would be a good model for it?

Edit: here is a closer view:

[image]

Comment: There is some good general advice at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10517/identify-probability-distributions.

Comment: @whuber: what I really wanted here was to get names of possible matches to read up on them and see if any of them make sense in my application.

Comment: Usually one does the opposite: the application suggests likely distributions.  Not only that, it also determines how to check whether a distribution is a reasonable fit.  For example, in some cases it's important to get a good fit to the right tail (the largest values), whereas in others it's important to get a fit that doesn't deviate too much at any percentage point.  Thus, some amplification on your part concerning the application would be helpful.

Comment: Any idea what the curve would look like if continued in the negative direction?  (It obviously looks exponential to the right.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have strictly positive data that is clearly skewed, so you need a distribution that includes the possibility for skew. The Gamma distribution, which has density

$$
p(x) = x^{k-1} \frac{e^{-x/\theta}}{\theta^k \, \Gamma(k)}\text{ for } x \geq 0\text{ and }k, \theta > 0 $$

is probably the default choice in the situation like this. There are other choices for skewed data (e.g. Skew-normal, log-normal, skew-logistic, weibull) but the gamma is more commonly used, and is directly related to some of the other choices (skew-logistic, weibull).

Comment: It's awfully hard to eyeball a distribution, but one can usually say what it's *not*.  In this case, the right tail is so heavy that the Gamma shape parameter $k$ has to exceed 1, but the nonzero mode shows it has to be less than 1; *ergo*, no Gamma is going to be a reasonable approximation for most purposes.

Comment: The tail length is also a function of $\theta$. You could have $k$ just barely larger than 1, say $1/.75$, while having $\theta$ just barely larger than 0, say, $1/25$, would create the long tail and the non-zero mode. In fact, a histogram of x=rgamma(10000,1/.8,1/25) looks pretty close to the one seen above.

Comment: typo.  look at the histogram of x=rgamma(10000,1/.75,1/25)

Comment: Not even close.  The histogram in the OP decays roughly like $1/x$ (*not* exponentially).  Its tail simply won't match any Gamma accurately.  Histograms are notoriously bad tools for judging distributions.  Constructing the q-q plot will show you what's wrong.

Comment: I didn't have the data set so I had nothing to compare to, which is why I used the histogram.

Comment: @whuber can you say a bit more about how the histogram above is obviously decaying like $1/x$? The height of the density corresponding to $x=100$ looks nowhere near twice as high as the $y$ corresponding to $x=200$. I could be making a rookie mistake here but I'd like to hear what you have to say

Comment: Here are the heights of the bars from the leftmost out to just beyond x=200 (accurate to about +-100): 90730
114284
99263
79374
70662
56121
51794
43202
40378
35631
33769
30704
28361
25176
22472
20610
18206
16330
14234
12943
11736
10233
9196
8349
7439
6486
5894
4984
4370
3989
3481
3205
2549
2232
1956
1618
1343
1300
1300
1067
1067
771
750
686.  The bar width is approximately 4.75.  There are many good ways to analyze this, so I'm interested in learning about your approach.